# PIG: How to Dynamically Pass N parameter values

Tags: apache-pig, parameter-passing

I have a growing list of IDs I would like to dynamically pass into a pig script to aid in processing data for a single column.

I'm manually passing param values, which isn't scalable.

Command EX:

```
pig --param id1=123 id2=456 id3=789 get foo.pig
```

Script example

```
A = load '$INPUT' using AvroStorage();
B = foreach A generate value.rawData#'id' as user_id:chararray;
C = FILTER B BY user_id == '$id1' or user_id == '$id2' OR user_id == '$id3'; 
DUMP C;
```

How can one dynamically pass N parameter values and have them applied to a regional operator for the same column?

Answer (score 0):

If I have to solve this problem I will :-

1> Create a simple text file (say id.txt) and keep on appending news ids to it.

2> Use id.txt inside my PIG script to JOIN with $INPUT file and records will be automatically filtered if id is not found :-

```
A = load '$INPUT' using AvroStorage();
A = foreach A generate value.rawData#'id' as user_id:chararray;
B = load 'id.txt' using PigStorage as (userId:chararrray);
C = JOIN A by user_id B by userId ; 
-- after above JOIN C will only contain records which has user_id in both files
DUMP C;
```